# How to position element beneath canvas on html css

Tags: html, css, three.js

I am trying to position the experience section beneath the canvas and title elements however, the experience section seems to overlap the canvas. I have tried increasing the margin left but it is still not working.

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:400,500,600,700&display=swap');

```
*{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: black;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

body,html{
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}


.webgl{
  position:absolute;

  
  
  
}


.title{
  color:white;
  z-index:1;
  
  margin-top: 300px;
  width:550px;

  font-size: 100px;
  font-weight: 800;
  outline: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #5335cf 0%, #de005e 25%, #f66e48 50%, #de005e 75%, #5335cf 100%);
  background-size: 400%;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent; 
  animation: animate 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate {
  to{
    background-position: 400%;
  }
}

.page{
  z-index: 2;
  position:absolute;
}





header .header-contain{
  display: flex;

}

.experience-section {
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  color: #333;
  margin-top: 400px;
  position:relative;
  
 
  
  

}
```

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="/vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Suneet's Portfolio</title>
    
  </head>
  <body>
    
    
    <canvas class="webgl"></canvas>
    <div class="page">
      
      <h1 class="title">
          Welcome to Suneets Portfolio

          
      </h1>
      

      <section class="experience-section">
        <h2>Work Experience</h2>
        <div class="experience">
          <p>work</p>
          <p>work</p>
          
        </div>
      </section>

  </div>


  


    <script type="module" src="/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I have tried increasing the margins and playing around with the position but nothing seems to be working.

Answer (score 1):

I created a Codepen using your code and I am trying to figure out what your problem is.

Some general issues in your code are:

- Here you're using a class to access the canvas. This is not often used so I just want to make sure that it's done on purpose

```
// What you're doing
<canvas class="webgl"></canvas> // Your HTML
document.getElementsByClassName('webgl')[0]; // What your JS probably looks like

// How most people would do it
<canvas id="webgl"></canvas> // HTML
document.getElementById('webgl'); // JS
```

- You're also repeating the `margin-top` property of the `.experience-section` class

```
.experience-section {
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  color: #333;
  margin-top: 400px; /* repeated */
  position: relative;
}
```

- Another issue is that you're setting the background color to black for all elements.

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background-color: black;
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}
```

As mentioned at the beginning I tried to fix these as well as some other issues to achieve the desired effect. I set the canvas animation to just be a spinning cube as you didn't provide any description of what it is.

If you meant something else then please let me know.

Here is the code I wrote.

HTML:

```
<head>
  <title>Suneet's Portfolio</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header">
      <div class="title">
        <h1>Welcome to Suneets Portfolio</h1>
      </div>
    <canvas class="webgl" id="webgl"></canvas>
  </header>

  <section class="experience-section">
    <h2>Work Experience</h2>
    <div class="experience">
      <p>work</p>
      <p>work</p>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

body,
html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.header {
  position: relative;
  
  /* center items */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  
  width: 100vw; /* vw means view width */
  height: 500px;
}

.webgl {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1; /* Below title */
  top: 0;
  
  height: 100%; /* fill the header */
  width: 100%; /* fill the header */
}

.title {
  display: absolute; /* This needs to be absolute */
  z-index: 10; /* On top of canvas */
  top: 0;
  
  /* center items */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

  height: 100%; /* fill the header */
  width: 100%; /* fill the header */
}

.title h1{
  color: white;
  
  text-align: center;
  
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 800;
  outline: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  background: linear-gradient(
    135deg,
    #5335cf 0%,
    #de005e 25%,
    #f66e48 50%,
    #de005e 75%,
    #5335cf 100%
  );
  background-size: 400%;
  background-clip: text;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
  animation: animate 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes animate {
  to {
    background-position: 400%;
  }
}

.page {
  background-color: black;
}

.experience-section {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  color: #333;
  position: relative;
}
```

JS for the spinning cube example:

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('webgl');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 10;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight - 10;

const vertSize = 4;
const focalLen = -350;
const rotationSpeed = 1;

let theta = 0;

let vertexes = [
  [100, 100, 100],
  [100, -100, 100],
  [-100, -100, 100],
  [-100, 100, 100],
  [100, 100, -100],
  [100, -100, -100],
  [-100, -100, -100],
  [-100, 100, -100]
];
let edges = [
  [0, 1],
  [1, 2],
  [2, 3],
  [3, 0],
  [4, 5],
  [5, 6],
  [6, 7],
  [7, 4],
  [0, 4],
  [1, 5],
  [2, 6],
  [3, 7]
];

addEventListener("resize", (event) => {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 10;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight - 10;
});

function rotateX(vert) {
  let x = vert[0];
  let y = vert[1];
  let z = vert[2];
  
  let xRot = x;
  let yRot = y * Math.cos(theta) + z * Math.sin(theta);
  let zRot = y * -Math.sin(theta) + z * Math.cos(theta);
  
  theta += 0.001;
  
  return [xRot, yRot, zRot];
}

function rotateY(vert) {
  let x = vert[0];
  let y = vert[1];
  let z = vert[2];
  
  let xRot = x * Math.cos(theta) + z * Math.sin(theta);
  let yRot = y;
  let zRot = x * -Math.sin(theta) + z * Math.cos(theta);
  
  theta += rotationSpeed / 2500;
  
  return [xRot, yRot, zRot];
}

function rotateZ(vert) {
  let x = vert[0];
  let y = vert[1];
  let z = vert[2];
  
  let xRot = x * Math.cos(theta) + y * Math.sin(theta);
  let yRot = x * -Math.sin(theta) + y * Math.cos(theta);
  let zRot = z;
  
  theta += rotationSpeed / 2500;
  
  return [xRot, yRot, zRot];
}

function project(vert) {
  let x = vert[0];
  let y = vert[1];
  let z = vert[2];
  
  x_disp = (focalLen * x) / (focalLen + z) + canvas.width/2;
  y_disp = (focalLen * y) / (focalLen + z) + canvas.height/2;
  
  return [x_disp, y_disp];
}

function drawPoints(x, y) {  
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(255,100,100)";
  ctx.arc(x, y, vertSize, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
}

function drawEdges(points) {
  for(let edge of edges) {
    let x1 = points[edge[0]][0];
    let y1 = points[edge[0]][1];
    
    let x2 = points[edge[1]][0];
    let y2 = points[edge[1]][1];
    
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = 2;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "rgb(255,255,255)";
    ctx.moveTo(x1, y1);
    ctx.lineTo(x2, y2);
    ctx.stroke();
  }
}

function animate() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  
  let points = [];
  
  for(let vert of vertexes) {
    let rotated = rotateY(rotateZ(rotateX(vert)));
    points.push(project(rotated));
  }
  
  for(let p of points) {
    drawPoints(p[0], p[1]);
  }
  
  drawEdges(points);
  
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

animate();
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Hey Michal thanks so much for your help, I really appreciate it. There is some white space between the header and experience section, do you know how to remove that?